# Convert from Flux to Mono

Tags: project-reactor

How can I convert from a Flux with 1 element to a Mono?

```
Flux.fromArray(arrayOf(1,2,1,1,1,2))
                .distinct()
                .take(1)
```

How do I make this a Mono(1)?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Instead of `take(1)`, you could use `next()`.

This will transform the `Flux` into a valued `Mono` by taking the first emitted item, or an empty Mono if the Flux is empty itself.

Answer (score 43):

Here is a list:

- `Flux#single` will work if there is one element from `Flux`. Eg: `flux.take(1).single();`
- `Flux#next` will get you the first element. Eg: `flux.next();`
- `Flux#last` for last element. Eg: `flux.last();`
- `Flux#singleOrEmpty` is similar to `Optional`. Eg: `flux.take(0).singleOrEmpty();`
- `Flux#collect`, it depends on use case.

  ```
    flux.collect(Collectors.reducing((i1, i2) -> i1))
        .map(op -> op.get());
  ```
- `Flux#elementAt` for i'th index. Eg: `flux.elementAt(1);`
- `Flux#shareNext` for first found element. `flux.shareNext();`
- `Flux#reduce` for reduction op. Eg: `flux.reduce((i1,i2) -> i1);`

Comment: I just saw `flux.take(0).singleOrEmpty()` and thought to mention that would appear to always produce an empty Mono as `take(0)` would never subscribe to the source

Answer (score 1):

Or,you could use single() on the filtered Flux

Answer (score 1):

Also the very simple way is to use [Mono.from()](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#from-org.reactivestreams.Publisher-)

```
Mono<Integer> mono = Mono.from(flux);
```

If your flux has more than one element, then it will just take the first element emitted by the flux.